# Expo + FirebaseAuthentication (with Twitter) doesn't work by error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I want to construct FirebaseAuthentication with Twitter using Expo.
But an error that the request token is invalid occurred.

Running the server-side program with my PC and Expo(client) side program with Expo app on my iPhone.

(* is each token and so on)

Server side (JavaScript)

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const OAuth = require('oauth-1.0a');
const qs = require('qs')
const HmacSHA1 = require('crypto-js/hmac-sha1')
const Base64 = require('crypto-js/enc-base64')

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

const config = {
  GOOGLE: {
    CLIENT_ID: "",
    CLIENT_SECRET: "",
  },
  GITHUB: {
    CLIENT_ID: "",
    CLIENT_SECRET: "",
  },
  TWITTER: {
    CLIENT_ID: "*****",
    CLIENT_SECRET: "*****",
  }
}

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/auth/google', async (req, res) => {

  async function createTokenWithGoogleCode(code, redirect_uri) {

    const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`
    const res = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        code,
        client_id: config.GOOGLE.CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: config.GOOGLE.CLIENT_SECRET,
        redirect_uri,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code'
      })
    });

    return await res.json()
  }

  return res.json(await createTokenWithGoogleCode(req.body.code, req.body.redirect_uri))
});

app.post('/auth/github', async (req, res) => {

  async function createTokenWithGithubCode(code) {
    const url =
      `https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token` +
      `?client_id=${config.GITHUB.CLIENT_ID}` +
      `&client_secret=${config.GITHUB.CLIENT_SECRET}` +
      `&code=${code}`;

    const res = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    return await res.json()
  }

  return res.json(await createTokenWithGithubCode(req.body.code))
});

app.post('/auth/twitter/request_token', async (req, res) => {

  const { redirect_uri } = req.body

  const oauth = OAuth({
    consumer: {
      key: config.TWITTER.CLIENT_ID,
      secret: config.TWITTER.CLIENT_SECRET,
    },
    signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
    hash_function: (baseString, key) => Base64.stringify(HmacSHA1(baseString, key))
  })

  const request_data = {
    url: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
    method: 'POST',
    data: { 
      oauth_callback: redirect_uri,
    }
  };

  const response = await fetch(request_data.url, {
    method: request_data.method,
    headers: oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize(request_data))
  })

  const text = await response.text();
  return res.json(qs.parse(text))
});

app.post('/auth/twitter/access_token', async (req, res) => {

  const { oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, oauth_verifier } = req.body

  const oauth = OAuth({
    consumer: {
      key: config.TWITTER.CLIENT_ID,
      secret: config.TWITTER.CLIENT_SECRET,
    },
    signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
    hash_function: (baseString, key) => Base64.stringify(HmacSHA1(baseString, key))
  })

  const request_data = {
    url: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      oauth_verifier,  
    },
  }

  const headers = oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize(request_data, {key: oauth_token, secret: oauth_token_secret}))

  const response = await fetch(request_data.url, {
    method: request_data.method,
    data: request_data.data,
    headers
  })

  if (response.status !== 200) {
    res.status = response.status
    return res.json({message: "something wrong"})
  }
  const text = await response.text();
  return res.json(qs.parse(text))
})

if (!module.parent) {
  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
  });
}

module.exports = app;
Expo
expo init expo && cd $_
yarn add firebase
```

Expo side (TypeScript)

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, Button, View } from 'react-native'
import { Facebook } from 'expo';
import * as AuthSession from "expo-auth-session"
import firebase from 'firebase';

const AUTH_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:3000"
const REDIRECT_URL = AuthSession.getRedirectUrl();
const FACEBOOK_APP_ID = ""
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = ""
const GITHUB_CLIENT_ID = ""

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "*****",
    authDomain: "*****",
    databaseURL: "*****",
    projectId: "*****",
    storageBucket: "*****",
    messagingSenderId: "*****"
  })
}

async function createTokenWithCode(provider, code) {
  const url = `${AUTH_BASE_URL}/auth/${provider}/`
  console.log(url)
  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      code,
      redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URL // Google で必要
    })
  })
  const json = await res.json();
  console.log(json)
  return json
}

async function getTwitterRequestToken() {
  const url = `${AUTH_BASE_URL}/auth/twitter/request_token`
  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URL
    })
  });
  return await res.json();
}

async function getTwitterAccessToken(params) {
  const { oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, oauth_verifier } = params
  const url = `${AUTH_BASE_URL}/auth/twitter/access_token`
  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, oauth_verifier })
  });
  return await res.json();
}

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      user: null
    }
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ user: user.toJSON() })
        console.log(user)
      } else {
        this.setState({ user: null })
      }
    })
  }

  handleLogout() { 
    firebase.auth().signOut()
  }



  async handleTwitterLogin() {
    const { oauth_token, oauth_token_secret } = await getTwitterRequestToken()

    const { params }  = await AuthSession.startAsync({
      authUrl: `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=${oauth_token}`
    });

    const oauth_verifier = params.oauth_verifier
    const result = await getTwitterAccessToken({oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, oauth_verifier})

    const credential = firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.credential(
      result.oauth_token, 
      result.oauth_token_secret
    )
    firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Firebase Authentication Example</Text>
        <Button onPress={this.handleTwitterLogin} title="Twitter" />
        <Button onPress={this.handleLogout} title="Logout" />
        <Text>displayName: {this.state.user && this.state.user.displayName}</Text>
        <Text>providerId: {this.state.user && this.state.user.providerData[0].providerId}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I referred to the following page.
https://qiita.com/okamuuu/items/6da12f295c3b8a7bc3d8

Please tell me the solution.

I'm sorry if I can't make you understood.

Comment: That's a lot of code, you'll need to be more specific about what is triggering the error you mention.

Comment: Sorry...
I don't know why it is.